# https files fail to play on iOS with 'AVPlayerItem.Status.failed'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, avaudioplayer

I'm running this simple program in flutter, on android it works regularly but on ios it gives me the error: 'AVPlayerItem.Status.failed'

added in .plist:
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

code:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  Duration totalDuration;
  Duration position;
  String audioState = '';

  initAudio() {
    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((presentDuration) {
      setState(() {
        totalDuration = presentDuration;
      });
    });
    audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((position) {
      setState(() {
        this.position = position;
      });
    });
    audioPlayer.onPlayerError.listen((event) {
      print("Errore: " + event.toString());
    });

    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
      if (event == PlayerState.PAUSED) audioState = "Pausa";
      if (event == PlayerState.PLAYING) audioState = "Playing...";
      if (event == PlayerState.STOPPED) audioState = "Fermato!";
      if (event == PlayerState.COMPLETED) audioState = "Completato";
      setState(() {});
    });

    audioPlayer.onPlayerError.listen((event) {
      print("Errore : " + event.toString());
    });
  }

  playAudio() {
    audioPlayer.play("https://api.spreaker.com/v2/episodes/43617247/play.mp3");
  }

  pauseAudio() {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  stopAudio() {
    audioPlayer.stop();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAudio();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(totalDuration.toString()),
            Text(position.toString().split(".").first),
            Text(audioState ?? "null"),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                initAudio();
              },
              child: Text("Init audio"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                playAudio();
              },
              child: Text("Play audio"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pauseAudio();
              },
              child: Text("Pause audio"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                stopAudio();
              },
              child: Text("Stop audio"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**this is my flutter doctor**

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-x64, locale

it-IT)

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices

✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.

Install Android Studio from:

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK

components.

(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup

for detailed instructions).

If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use

flutter config --android-sdk to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at

/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)

! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)

print in console:

flutter : Errore: AVPlayerItem.Status.failed

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: I still haven't found any solution